# Maximize the Profit in an array

Tags: algorithm

I having an Two Array `A` and `B` where A represent the Value and B represent the weight.I want to collect any number of element such that weight does not exceeded `N` and the profit is Maximum 
For Example:

```
A[0]=2 B[0]=2
A[1]=3 B[1]=1
A[2]=3 B[2]=2
if N=4 , so profit is maximum with A[1] A[2]
```

I am not asking for a code.I am asking is there any standard algorithm for this or this program is to be reduced to a graph level and then solve it using some standard algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [the Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It's often solved with [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/
```

The above link give you a code for your problem which is solved using dynamic programming.

Comment: Please explain it further.